# Monero blockchain usage after importing .raw file

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui

I am wondering how to use blockchain after conversion of the .raw file through `blockchain-import`. I already have a data.mdb file, but it seems like the new .raw file is bigger now, so I have to sync it again. It took 4 days to import the .raw file to .mdb. Is there any way to use GUI to sync the rest?

When I try to use the .mdb directory it starts syncing again from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little reason to be downloading and importing the raw blockchain these days. Just running the daemon and letting it sync the blockchain is almost always the best approach. If for whatever reason you *need* to download and import the raw file instead, you should follow [the guide](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html).

Addressing some specific points in your question:

> It took 4 days to import .raw file

Then you are most likely using a spinning disk. The Monero blockchain is best suited to solid state drives. It will sync on spinning HDDs, but take longer. If you plan on keeping the node running 24/7, using a HDD is fine, because once synced, the slowness won't impact you. If however you are *not* going to keep your node running 24/7, you will certainly want to either have the blockchain on an SSD or use a remote node.

> Is there any way to use GUI to sync the rest?

It will do so automatically.

> When I try to use the .mdb directory it starts syncing again from 0?

If after importing a raw file, your daemon starts syncing from zero, you have something pointed at the wrong data dir. Note also there is a difference between syncing the blockchain and scanning the blockchain. If you are using the GUI after importing the blockchain, it will still need to scan the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to use .raw file due to my Tails shutting down in unexpected moments (later figured out it was caused by not enough space on disk).I will use SSD next time. Figured out the data dir was wrong - it referenced \home not \media mounted partition. This is why it started from 0. Silly me!